# jquery: add php include file to jquery content?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the following jquery:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'rl',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)',
    content:'this is my new content'
});
}, 2500);
</script>
```

what I am trying to do is replace the content of the jquery where it says 'this is my new content' with a php file called login_form.php.

I have tried the following:

```
content:'<?php include 'login_form.php'; ?>'
```

however this does not work. if I use php within the content my jquery just stops working all together. my login_form.php file includes a form with 2 input boxes. can someone please show me how this can be done, thanks in advance

Comment: why has this question been marked down? if you are going to mark down a question please give your reason. thanks

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What is the content of login_form.php? If you view the source of the page, can you see if the include of the php file worked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you are running into problems because the rendered PHP page will contain unescaped single quotes, which will clash with the single quotes you are using to define the string (below) from your example:

```
content:'<?php include 'login_form.php'; ?>'
```

**Answer:** If, instead, you were to actually include the rendered content into a hidden element of the page/DOM, then you could access it that way and assign it.

```
<div id="loginSource" style="visibility: hidden;"><?php include 'login_form.php'; ?></div>
```

Then you could do something like this for the assignment:

```
<script>
var loginSource = $("#loginSource").html();
setTimeout(function() {
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'rl',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)',
    content: loginSource
});
}, 2500);
</script>
```

This is just a guess.  I've not tested it.  I don't actually ever work in PHP.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

the file that has the script has to be a php file or it won't work, because it will not be parsed by php.

Let me know if that's the case...